# Google Marker Clustering. How to add this lib to project? Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

There are multiple instructions on installing Google Marker Clustering library, e.g: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/setup
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Swift.md

But non of them didn't work for me. Also, they have some contradictions. I tried to add pod, tried to add bridging file etc. 
My "import" doesn't know about anything like clustering

How can I make it work?

Comment: Why doesn't Google's guide (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/setup) work for you? Can you please share the errors you got when you followed the guide and the exact steps you took?

Comment: @evan, 1. Guide, provided in your link is supported only for using with static libraries, loaded with Pods.
2. Instruction on Bridging-Header didn't work for me
3. I've also used instruction from GoogleMaps Utils on GitHub, which also didn't work and had conflicts with guide, provided by you. 

But everything is fine now. I found a solution and posted in in answer. Thank you for your interest

Comment: Thanks for your update, glad to hear you found a workaround! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to fix this issue. After adding files as Google provided in it's guide, do this steps:

1. Create file "AppName-Bridging-Header.h".
2. Import new libraries like so:

   #ifndef Bridging_Header_h

   #define Bridging_Header_h

   #import "GMUMarkerClustering.h"

   #import "GMUGeoJSONParser.h"

   #import "GMUKMLParser.h"

   #import "GMUGeometryRenderer.h"

   #endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
3. Go to project settings.
4. Chose "Targets" field and "Build settings" menu.
5. Search for "Swift compiler" setting.
6. Add setting "Objective-c bridging header" and path to your file, in my case: "AppName/App/AppName-Bridging-Header.h[image]

Done! You have this clustering library in your app.